# QTimer::singleShot not calling my timeout slot

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qt4.8

I call singleshot in a button press callback, but my timeout slot never gets called, in the debugger my code gets to where i call the singleshot function, but it never gets to the breakpoint in my timeout function.

In the .h:

```
private slots:

void on_snoozeTimeout(Data d);
```

In the .cpp:

```
void MyClass::on_snoozeBtn_clicked()
{                   
   QTimer::singleShot(snoozeTimeoutValue*1000,this,SLOT(on_snoozeTimeout(selectedData)));
}
void MyClass::on_snoozeTimeout(Data d)
{
//not hitting this breakpoint
}
```

Comment: `SLOT(on_snoozeTimeout(selectedData))` is not correct. You can't tie a member variable like this. It would need to be `SLOT(on_snoozeTimeout(Data))` but then QTimer would not send this value for the time out: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout) You probably need a lambda expression.

Comment: @drescherjm so I can't pass a parameter into a slot?

Comment: Not the way you want. A lambda like the current answer can solve this if you have Qt5 or greater.

Comment: I am using qt 4.8

Comment: A lambda can not work with Qt-4.8. The solution will be more difficult. You probably have to describe where the `selectedData` variable comes from for someone to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The `SLOT` macro can't accept function parameters the way you are trying to use it. Use a lambda instead:

```
QTimer::singleShot(snoozeTimeoutValue*1000, [this, selectedData](){
    on_snoozeTimeout(selectedData);
});
```

Comment: I get this error: ‘selectedData’ is not captured
             on_snoozeTimeout(selectedData);
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Well, your example code didn't explain where that came from. Add it to the lambda capture. I'll make an edit.

Comment: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘}’ token
     }
     ^

Comment: I missed the closing paren.

Comment: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function

Comment: Then add `this` to the capture list.

Comment: no matching function for call to: QTimer::singleShot(int, MyClass::on_snoozeBtn_clicked()::<lambda()>)’
         });
          ^

Answer (score 0):

Using qt4.8, refactored code to not use parameter